# How to avoid cutting text in the middle of line when overflow set for parent?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have fixed height grid items with title and description. Title and description have different length and font-size. I need to show title fully (usually takes 1 - 4 lines) and the rest space should take description. How to avoid cutting description in the middle of the line? [image]

```css
.item{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.title{
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.description{
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="title">
    One line title
  </div>
  
  <div class="description">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="title">
    Two lines very long title
  </div>
  
  <div class="description">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but what if I have 3 or 4 lines? In some cases maybe even 5...

Comment: One suggestion... You may use `min-height` equal to largest value of all of titles like. Try adding `min-height: 62px` in styles of `.title` in your snippet.

Comment: Essentially, **you can't**. I'd suggest you find another method of sizing the boxes other than a **fixed height** which is the source of the issue. Flexbox or CSS-Grid can help here.

Comment: The only other option is forcing multiline text overflow ellipsis..and there's a whole bunch of SO questions on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't offer you a solution per se as I don't think a decent one exists. However, might I suggest removing the fixed height that is causing the issue and instead use something like flexbox to match the item heights with that of the tallest item in the row? It's a different approach but is far more flexible.

In addition to matching the heights I would also consider limiting the length of the string returned (if it becomes too uncomfortable) using a server side language like SQL, PHP or C# or trim it and show the full text in a title tag.

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: 0 1 calc(50% - 20px);
}

.title {
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.description {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">
      One line title
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">
      One line title
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">
      Two lines very long title
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">
      Two lines very long title
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">
      Two lines very long title
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">
      Two lines very long title
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Truncation:

Here are a few methods for truncating text in various languages:

### SQL

```
select 
  left(column, 150) + '...' column
from yourtable
```

### PHP

```
substr($string,0, 150);
```

### C Sharp

```
string.Substring(0, 150);
```

### JS

```
string.substring(0, 150);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `min-height` to the title to push the content a little and avoid breaking text when the title is one line.

You can also adjust the `line-height` of the first line of the title to be different from the other and this will help you to fix the issue with multi-line titles (if of course you are ok with changing this value) :

```css
.item {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.title {
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  min-height: 40px;
}

.title:first-line {
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.description {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="title">
    One line title
  </div>

  <div class="description">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="title">
    Two lines very long title
  </div>

  <div class="description">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="title">
    Two lines very long title very long title
  </div>

  <div class="description">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="title">
    Two lines very long title very long title title very long title
  </div>

  <div class="description">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="title">
    Two lines very long title very long title title very long title long title
  </div>

  <div class="description">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to have the first line of title the same height as the rest lines?

Comment: @Natasha unfortunately that's the issue :) but am thinking about a solution !

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy solution to this.

You can adjust the `line-height` and `margin` values of the `.title` to ensure that the text doesn't cut awkwardly.

For a title with 3 lines, one option (for webkit browsers) is to add `text-overflow: ellipsis` and use `line-clamp` to keep the text on 2 lines.

For what it's worth, I think a tighter line height on the title looks a better too.

```css
.item {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.title {
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.description {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="title">
    One line title
  </div>

  <div class="description">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="title">
    Two lines very long title
  </div>

  <div class="description">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="title">
    Three lines makes a very long title
  </div>

  <div class="description">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```